# how to remove rows in a dataframe that contains all zeros or NAs or in combination of zeros and NAs in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a large data frame with 10000000 rows and 150 columns. in the dataset, there are specific rows that contain all zeros or all NAs or a combination of zeros and NAs. the sample dataframe is shown below

```
df <- data.frame(x = c('q', 'w', 'e', 'r','t', 'y'), a = c('a','b','c','d','e','f'), b = 
c(0,1,2,3,0,5), c= c(0,3,2,4,0,'NA'), d=c(0,2,5,7,'NA',5), e = c(0,5,'NA',3,0,'NA'), f = 
c(0,7,4,3,'NA',7))
```

the desired output is as follows

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c('w', 'e', 'r','y'), a = c('b','c','d','f'), b = c(1,2,3,5), c= 
c(3,2,4,'NA'), d=c(2,5,7,5), e = c(5,'NA',3,'NA'), f = c(7,4,3,7))
```

i.e.

```
df <- 
w b 1 3  2 5  7
e c 2 2  5 NA 4
r d 3 4  7 3  3
y f 5 NA 5 NA 7
```

I tried multiple possible solutions in the stackover flow such as

```
df %>% 
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~ !is.na(.x)))
```

or

```
df %>%
```

filter_if(is.numeric,
~ !is.na(.))

but could not solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply()` rowwise, combining `all()` and `na.omit()`

```
df[apply(df[,-c(1,2)],1,\(r) all(na.omit(r)!=0)),]
```

Output:

```
 x a b  c d  e f
2 w b 1  3 2  5 7
3 e c 2  2 5 NA 4
4 r d 3  4 7  3 3
6 y f 5 NA 5 NA 7
```

Comment: i am getting error like this "Error: unexpected input in "df <- df[apply(df[,-c(1,2,)],1,\"" @langtang

Comment: perhaps you are using an old version of R?  Use `function(r)` instead of the short cut `\(r)`

Comment: after updating the R version, it worked @langtang

Answer (score 0):

We may use vectorized operations as it is a big dataset

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(!if_all(where(is.numeric), ~ is.na(.x)|.x %in% 0))
```

-output

```
  x a b  c d  e f
1 w b 1  3 2  5 7
2 e c 2  2 5 NA 4
3 r d 3  4 7  3 3
4 y f 5 NA 5 NA 7
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[df[, !Reduce(`&`, lapply(.SD, \(x) is.na(x)| x %in% 0)), 
      .SDcols = is.numeric]]
```

-output

```
       x      a     b      c      d      e      f
   <char> <char> <num> <char> <char> <char> <char>
1:      w      b     1      3      2      5      7
2:      e      c     2      2      5     NA      4
3:      r      d     3      4      7      3      3
4:      y      f     5     NA      5     NA      7
```

Comment: i am getting error as follows " Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x could not find function "if_all"
i Input `..1` is `!if_all(where(is.numeric), ~is.na(.x) | .x %in% 0)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred." @akrun

Comment: dplyr package version is 1.0.2 @akrun

Comment: in the second solution, there is some error showing in the code at "\(x)" @akrun

Comment: @Kumar What is your `R version`

Comment: after updating the R version, both the code versions worked but did not solve the problem. it did not remove any row in the dataframe @akrun

Comment: @Kumar If you are asking about the original data, you need to update it. i.e. `df <- df %>%
   filter(!if_all(where(is.numeric), ~ is.na(.x)|.x %in% 0))`